# How to extend a variable name to fetch another?

Tags: templating, variable, set

I’m trying to append a 'x2' to the end of a variable name to call another variable.

For example:

imgSize might be set to predefined variables like imgColumn4, imgColumn6 or imgColumn8.
In that case I would also have imgColumn4x2, imgColumn6x2 and imgColumn8x2.

So to simplify the variables in a loop, I’d like to do something like:

```
{% set imageUrl = image.getUrl(imgSize) %}
{% set imageUrlx2 = image.getUrl(imgSize ~ 'x2') %}
```

`imgSize ~ 'x2'` does not work.

How can I join 'imgSize' and 'x2'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other ways also, but one approach is to use an array with key value pairs, which can be assigned and accessed more dynamically.

```
{{ sizeVars[imgSize ~ 'x2'] }}
```

You also might want to check out twigs `attribute` method.

```
{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

Where 'item' can be a concatenated string.